# Can't step in ipdb when invoked in Jupyter Lab

Tags: debugging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am having a problem with ipdb when invoking it using `%debug` (possibly in other cases, too). It is shown in the following video. If I run the `%debug` magic in a console or in the notebook, and get the ipdb field, if I try to advance to the next step using `n` or `s`, the cursor simply moves back to the console and it does not advance to the next line.

I'm using Jupyter Lab 1.1.4

Thanks.

[image: ipdb troubleshooting]

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a Jupyter Lab specific problem.
I'm seeing the same behavior in Spyder.
In fact, I don't know of it *is* a problem. I'm not sure what the expected result should be here. I don't thinks it makes much sense to move one step beyound what triggered your error. That would probably just lead to another error. To obtain the functionality you're looking for here, it seems you should rather use `d` or `u`. Consider this snippet:

```
def foo(a,b):
    return(a+b)
c = foo(a=1, b=str(1))
```

When you run it, a `TypeError` is raised. If you now run `%debug` in a cell below, you'll see this:

[image]

Now, `d` will give you nothing since you are at the 'end' of your error:

[image]

But if you run `u`, you'll see that  arrow `---->` indicating your steps is moved one step previous to what triggered the error.

[image]

Now you can run `d` again, and you'll get back to where it all started:

[image]